# Stored procedure parameter data type that allows alphanumeric values

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure for SQL 2000 that has an input parameter with a data type of varchar(17) to handle a vehicle identifier (VIN) that is alphanumeric.  However, whenever I enter a value for the parameter when executing that has a numerical digit in it, it gives me an error.  It appears to only accept alphabetic characters.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you invoking the stored procedure - i.e. from Query Analyzer / SSMS, or from code - if code, what type?  Also - what error do you get?

Comment: Using SQL Query Analyzer (ex.: storedProc <VIN here>)

Comment: Error = Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'gn'.  I entered "1gn" without the double quotes (statement is a "like" not equal, so you can enter a portion of vin).

Comment: You need to enter it delimited in single quotes.

Comment: If I input just gn1, I just found it accepts it. It doesn't like the string to start with a numeric digit. The input VIN string has delimiters (') inserted around it in the code when it builds the query.

Comment: You should be using parameterised queries but in any event it clearly isn't quoted correctly when it reaches SQL Server. Is the stored procedure building a dynamic SQL string? Please show the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comments, there is a subtle "feature" of SQL Server that allows letters a-z to be used as stored proc parameters without delimiters. It's been there forever (since 6.5 at least)

I'm not sure of the full rules, but it's demonstrated in [MSDN (rename SQL Server etc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx): there are no delimiters around the "local" parameter. And I just found this [KB article on it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303774)

In this case, it could be starting with a number that breaks. I assume it works for a contained number (but as I said I'm not sure of the full rules).

Edit: confirmed by Martin as "breaks with leading number", OK for "containing number"

Comment: `exec ('create proc #P @x varchar(50) as select @x ') exec #P bar` works. `exec #P bar1` works. `exec #P 1bar` fails. This is clearly the issue that the parameter values are not being quoted.

Comment: YOU DA MAN (gbn)! That was it! Once I single-quote delimited that input parameter as '1gn' it works. Ironically, if you don't precede the input parameter for the VIN with a numeric digit (ex: gn6) it works fine without the delimiters -- go figure!

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't help much, but somewhere, you have a bug, typo, or oversight in your code. I spent 2+ years working with VINs as parameters, and other than regretting not having made it char(17) instead ov varchar(17), we never had any problems passing in alphanumeric VIN values. Somewhere, and I'd guess it's in the application layer, something is not liking digits -- perhaps a filter looking for only alphabetical characters?

Comment: It doesn't even execute the code in the SQL stored procedure.  It immediately fails at the point where it processes the input parameters.